# How to get Inset Buttons like that of iOS Maps app modal?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton

**`Swift 4.2`** implemented views **`programmatically`** only

I have created a `stack view` and put four buttons in it but they are just simple buttons without any gray background.

I want to achieve the exact four buttons in my stackview equally centered as like as - 
[image]

```
button.contentEdgeInset //Not working
```

This is what I tried -

```
 let feedbackButton:UIButton = {
    let origImage = UIImage(named: "feedback")
    let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setBackgroundImage(tintedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    button.tintColor = .systemPinkColor
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 40)
//  button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 50)
//  button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 50)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(feedbackFaculty), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

Output - 
[image]

The button's image gets stretched along with insets. `button.imageInsets` and `button.titleInsets` not working.
Help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code as to what you have tried that's not working, other than trying set the `contentEdgeInset`?

Comment: Also, post an image of what you are **currently** getting (that is not what you want).

Comment: I have edited the post, you can now see the edits! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Swift 4.2 implemented views programmatically only"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image doesn't follow the content insets. So this line:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(tintedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
button.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
```

Also, here's a couple things to note (per Apple's `UIButton` documentation):

> Supply a title string or image; size the button appropriately for your content.

Which implies that you cannot set an image and title at the same time, this might be why you're noticing `titleInset` and `imageInset` not playing nicely.

However, if you just set appropriate constraints for the buttons and set insets for the title OR the image you should be able to get the look you want. Also make sure your stack view is configured to use equal spacing for it's distribution.

The `imageInset` for each button in the image below is `(20, 20, 20, 20)`.

[image]